# How to start an appwidget configuration activity from an intent

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

I am setting up an App Widget,  When the user adds the widget to their home screen, It pops up with my configuration activity.

but now I need my user to login, SO i redirect them to my login activty,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (!isLoggedIn()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AppWidgetConfigureActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Source", "widgetConfig");
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finnish();
    }
```

But now when my login activity has successfully logged in, I need to create my appwidget config intent and start it up again.

But im not sure how to do this, because the config activity contains information like the widget id etc.

How can I start-up my config activity again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer may be as simple as not calling `finish()`. This will keep you configuration activity on the task stack and when the login activity finishes, the configuration activity will be displayed again.

If you used [`startActivityForResult`](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html), you could use your login activity to get some data that can be used when coming back to your own activity.

Comment: I initially did this, But then all the views in my activity are populated with data that can only be obtained once I have logged in, So if I do that, when I come back to the activity, all my views are empty as they failed to load tier data